# How to make question community wiki

Tags: support, status-bydesign

How do I make this question community wiki?
[graphs from real-life problems](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/graphs-from-real-life-problems)

Comment: Flag for mod attention and mention that you want it to be made CW.

Comment: I seem to recall seeing a "community wiki" checkbox, why isn't it there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The policy on making questions CW changed, because people on Stackoverflow with edit capabilities were making posts CW without proper consideration (note that CW is irreversible). So it was felt that this should be left up to the moderators with their infinite wisdom (HA!). As Robin suggests, flag the post and your friendly neighborhood moderator will eventually trundle over and make it CW.